# Is it possible to install Ubuntu (without crouton) on Samsung Chromebook 2 (XE503C32)?

Tags: samsung, chromebook

There is no more updates for ChromeOS. Support ended on June 2019. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6220366?hl=en

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on Samsung Chromebook 2 (XE503C32), processor ARM, memory 4Gb, eMMC 16GB?

Comment: Yes, although with those specs, I would opt for Lubuntu/LDXE. While you could run standard Ubuntu just fine with that, you'll have a snappier experience with LDXE

Comment: Here is how to https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466